# why can not php artisan migrate laravel

Tags: php, laravel

when I tried php artisan migrate an error :

```
{"error":{"type":"Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'laravel.users' (SQL: drop table `users`)","file":"\/opt\/lampp\/htdocs\/laravel\/coba1\/latihan3\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Connection.php","line":625}}
```

I use the mysql database, please give solution

Comment: Please provide some source from your users migration in `database/migrations` and also what is the name of your database in `.env`?

Comment: Your error message suggests you are trying to rollback a migration, are you running `php artisan migrate:refresh` by any chance? As per the error it is trying to drop a table that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to drop a table that does not exist. You are either not using the correct database (*laravel*) or you are doing this as part of a rollback or modification.

Remember that your migrations should include a function that makes changes (*up*) and a function that undoes those changes (*down*). [Database: Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#renaming-and-dropping-tables)

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // columns
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}
```

If you are dropping a table that you are not sure exists you can

```
Schema::dropIfExists('users');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check database name (it should be 'laravel' named or change yor config file to right database name) and check existing  table users in your database.